# Ruta de un JAR en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: java, rutas

Hola que tal buenas a todos. Pueden ayudarme? soy relativamente nuevo en JAVA.

Deseo saber como obtener el directorio de mi aplicación .jar en tiempo de ejecución. Deseo que el programa pueda obtenerlo sin importar en donde se encuentre el ejecutable jar

estoy trabajando en windows y en Netbeans.
he intentado lo siguiente:

```
    File file = new File("a.txt"); // creo un archivo y al no 
                                             //colocarle una ruta especifica
                                             // se guarda por defecto en la 
                                             //misma carpeta donde esta el 
                                             //ejecutable jar

    String ruta = "" + file.getAbsolutePath() ; // luego obtengo la ruta 
                                                //total de el archivo que acabo de crear y 
                                                //obtengo la ruta de donde 
                                                //se encuentra el ejecutable jar
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto mi programa en el IDE, me devuelve la ruta del proyecto mientras que si ejecuto mi programa desde el .jar entonces si me devuelve la ruta de donde se encuentra el jar, siento que esto se debe a que no es la manera mas adecuada de hacerlo.
existe alguna otra forma de obtener el directorio? realmente no me convence del todo la solución que estoy usando.

Comment: Gracias por la critica, he modificado mi pregunta, puedes ayudarme?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Java está funcionando correctamente. Considera que cuando ejecutas el proyecto desde tu IDE, la carpeta del proyecto **es** la ubicación del Jar. ¿Qué es lo que necesitas?

Comment: el directorio de mi proyecto es C:\Users\Cony Brown Sally\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Task Manager        y el directorio del jar es  C:\Users\Cony Brown Sally\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Task Manager\dist                    cuando ejecuto mi programa desde el ide me devuelve la primer ruta y cuando ejecuto el jar me devuelve la segunda ruta. acaso no debería devolverme siempre la segunda ruta? esta variabilidad es la que me preocupa ya que pretendo ejecutar el jar en otras computadoras y deseo que siempre me devuelva el directorio desde el que se ejecuta el jar

Comment: Ajá. ¿Eso cómo se asocia al problema que tienes? ¿Cuál es tu duda en concreto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según , la respuesta es:

- Si quieres obtener la ubicación exacta del jar que está en ejecución, usa:

  ```
    getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
  ```
- Si quieres obtener la ubicación donde se mandó a ejecutar el jar, usa:

  ```
    new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
  ```

Ojo que la clase `File` es una representación abstracta de un archivo o carpeta. Crear una instancia de `File` no significa que vas a crear físicamente el archivo/carpeta.

---

Puedes incluir this como documento desde un java

> this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

te devuelve una ruta cuando ejecutas desde un IDE y otra cuando ejecutas desde el cmd inspecciona la ruta proporcionada desde el IDE y desde ahi puedes hacer todo lo que necesites con los archivos solo concatena la consulta como por ejemplo

> this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()+"templates/PDFs/";

esa ruta seria la proporcional a tus archivos en el src
aunque cambies de ubicacion el archivo o se deje de ejecutar en una carpeta especifica

Answer (score 1):

La única condición es que el archivo a buscar se encuentre en el mismo directorio de nuestro .jar, quedándose así:

```
    File f = new File("ruta.txt"); // Creamos un objeto file
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); // Llamamos al método que                        
                                            //devuelve la ruta absoluta
```

Comment: Como bien te dije la única condición es que el archivo se encuentre en nuestro directorio del .jar o del proyecto. En el caso de que ejecutes desde el proyecto, como mencionas te devolverá su ruta absoluta, pero por que tu archivo se encuentra indexado allí.